How to filter data on a Listview from Firebase if the related data are on seperate nodes?
I have two versions of the same application, an admin and a client version.
The client version can report the following Emergency Types:
Medical Assistance, Police Assistance, and Fire Assistance
While the admin version has departments on their credentials:
Police, Hospital, Fire Dept
I want the listview on my admin version to only show the following:
Police Assistance for admin users with Police, Medical Assistance for admin users with Hospital, and so on...
This is my database layout (I've selected 'Police' as the department for testing):
{
  "Admin Users": {
    "vnpLogkr7pYndxx40XJB5PVulea2": {
      "Department": {
        "Fire Dept": 0,
        "Hospital": 0,
        "Police": 1
      },
      "Name": "Rafael Aurelius"
    }
  },

"Users": {
    "W5RZg4leD0XR6ZWCNClr9Dt99XG3": {
      "Scenario": "Scenario 2",
      "emergencyType": "Police Assistance",
      "userTimestamp": 1712208811229
    }
  }

I've set values on each Department, 1 if selected, and 0 if not, as I was planning on basing the filtering on the user access blocking system I previously implemented, but so far I've had no success with the filtering yet.
This is the listview without the filtering:
package com.example.rescuealertadmin;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class LocationLog extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseListAdapter<MainData> locationAdapter;
    ListView locationList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_locationlog);

        this.locationList = findViewById(R.id.locationView);

        
        Query filteredQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        FirebaseListOptions<MainData> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<MainData>()
                .setLayout(R.layout.location_item)
                .setQuery(filteredQuery, MainData.class)
                .build();

        locationList.setAdapter(locationAdapter);
        locationAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<MainData>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(@NonNull View v, @NonNull MainData model, int position) {
                TextView emergencyTypeView = v.findViewById(R.id.emergencyText);
                TextView scenarioView = v.findViewById(R.id.ScenarioText);
                Button emergencyButton = v.findViewById(R.id.itemButton);
                emergencyTypeView.setText(model.getEmergencyType());
                scenarioView.setText(model.getScenario());
                String selectedUid = locationAdapter.getRef(position).getKey();

                emergencyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Get the location data of the selected user
                        assert selectedUid != null;
                        DatabaseReference selectedUserLocationRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                .getReference().child("User Location").child(selectedUid);

                        selectedUserLocationRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot locationSnapshot) {
                                if (locationSnapshot.exists()) {
                                    Double latitude = locationSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                                    Double longitude = locationSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);

                                    if (latitude != null && longitude != null) {
                                        // Data retrieved successfully, now start the new activity
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(LocationLog.this, EmergencyDetails.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("Emergency Type", model.getEmergencyType());
                                        intent.putExtra("Scenario", model.getScenario());
                                        intent.putExtra("Latitude", latitude);
                                        intent.putExtra("Longitude", longitude);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    } else {
                                        // Handle missing location data
                                        Log.e(TAG, "Latitude or Longitude is null");
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    // Handle if the location data for the selected user doesn't exist
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Location data does not exist for UID: " + selectedUid);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError locationError) {
                                // Handle location data retrieval error
                                Log.e(TAG, "Location data retrieval error: " + locationError.getMessage());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                Log.d(TAG, "Emergency Type: " + model.getEmergencyType());
            }
        };


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (locationAdapter != null) {
            locationAdapter.startListening();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (locationAdapter != null) {
            locationAdapter.stopListening();
        }
    }
}

What are the ways to filter this data successfully on the listview?

To understand better, do you need to get all admin users who have a particular department, for example, the Police? Or do you need to get all admin users who have multiple departments, at once?

It's the other way around, I want to get all the users who have Police Assistance only on the list if the current admin users have the Police department.

To clarify, you need to get all users (not admins) where the emergencyType field holds the value of Police Assistance, and what about admins?

The admins only have a single department per registered. In this case, it's Police, I only need to get the department of the current user.

So you only need to read the departments of a signed-in admin, and based on a particular department get all users who have the emergencyType field set to that department?

Yes, that's correct

Ok, I'll write you answer right away.

According to answers in the comment, please use the following lines of code:
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference uidRef = db.child("Admin Users").child(uid);
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            DataSnapshot policeSnapshot = snapshot.child("Department").child("Police");
            if (policeSnapshot.exists()) {
                DatabaseReference usersRef = db.child("Users");
                Query queryByDepartment = usersRef.orderByChild("emergencyType").equalTo("Police" + " Assistance");
                queryByDepartment.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            DataSnapshot usersSnapshot = task.getResult();
                            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : usersSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                String scenario = userSnapshot.child("Scenario").getValue(String.class);
                                Log.d("TAG", scenario);
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});

This code reads the node of the authenticated admin, then it checks if the Police department node exists, and if it does it performs a query inside the users nodes, to get all users who have the emergencyType field set to "Police Assistance", and in the end prints the value of Scenario field in the logcat. According to your database schema, the result in the logcat will be:
Scenario 2


Thank you, but what if the admin user selected a different department? E.g. Hospital or Fire Dept and it would to have their associated emergencyType displayed?

Yes, because most likely the user choice is something dynamic. One more recommendation is to name the department in the same way you name the department type. For example, if the department type is called Police, the emergencyType field should also hold the value of Police and not Police Assistance. In this way, there is no need to use any concatenation like .equalTo("Police" + " Assistance").

Thanks again, I'll try the you have provided and work with it more.
